# strange free() invalid pointer C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free, realloc

I have a problem with this piece of code that I modified many times (but the error always appeared):
It seems it has an error in freeing the last index of "filter"

```
char** read_and_filter(int fd) {
  char buf[MAXLENGTH];
  char **bufs=NULL;
  char ch;
  int j = 0, len = 0, t = 0;
  while (!t && read(fd,&ch,1) == 1) {
    switch (ch) {
    case '\n':
      t = 1;
    case ' ':
      bufs = realloc(bufs, (j+1)*sizeof(char*));
      bufs[j++] = strndup(buf,len);
      memset(buf,0,len);
      len = 0;
      break;
    default:
      buf[len++] = ch;
    }
  }
  bufs[j] = 0;
  return bufs;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char **filter;
  int i,fd = open("input.txt",O_RDONLY);
  filter = read_and_filter(fd);
  for(i = 0; filter[i]; i++) {
    printf("%s\n",filter[i]);
    free(filter[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
0x1521030
HOME
0x1521050
2
0x1521070
A
0x1521010
8
0x15210c0
D
*** Error in `./test': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00000000015210c0 ***
```

I also tried to debug it with valgrind (it says me that the allocator tries to free 9 byte while the sum of characters is 8, strange no?) and gdb but nothing worked.
The first line of input.txt is "HOME 2 A 8 D\n"

Comment: Variable names that have no documentation value make kittens cry. `j`? `t`? Ok, easy enough to figure them out when taking time to read the code but you can make it easier with reasonable naming. Even if you don't care to make it easier for yourself, when you're asking other people to help with your problem without compensation, you owe it to them to make the task as simple for them as possible. Beyond that, your output does not seem to match the program you provided; there are what appear to be pointer values before each string which your code as shown doesn't print.

Comment: These statements created problem while freeing - `buf[len++] = ch;` . As you change to what the pointer points to .

Comment: @ameyCU Umm, no, that doesn't change any pointers in any way

Comment: There's also a break statement that should probably be in `case '\n'`. If you intend for code to flow through the next without a break, you really want to put a comment there to indicate it.

Comment: Allocation size is 9 because of the embedded `NUL` in C strings

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen ohh yes ,  mixed up `bufs` with `buf` .

Comment: It seems that the final bufs[j]=0 writes past what is allocated for bufs. Imagine in the last pass through the loop  j is 10. You then reallocate bufs to hold 11 char pointers and increment j. J is now 11. bufs[11] now writes to the 12th element of an array that can hold only 11 elements.

Comment: You always need at least 1 `char *` for the terminating null pointer, so you might as well initialize `char** bufs = malloc(sizeof(char*));` and change the realloc to `bufs = realloc(bufs, (j+2)*sizeof(char*));`.

Answer (score 7):

The first time these lines are executed

```
bufs = realloc(bufs, (j+1)*sizeof(char*));
bufs[j++] = strndup(buf,len);
```

you obtain memory for 1 pointer (j was 0). This leaves no space for the closing `NULL` you write at the end of the function with

```
bufs[j] = 0;
```

so you are writing beyond the allocated memory, thus have *undefined behaviour*. Similarly each time you extend the buffer length.

Comment: If I take bufs[j] = 0 off the error is:                                                       0x1a14030
HOME
0x1a14050
2
0x1a14070
A
0x1a14010
8
0x1a140c0
D
0x21                                                                                                           Segmentation Fault

Comment: You must allocate one more element than you do. `realloc(bufs, (j+2)*sizeof(char*))`

Comment: You must also `free(filter)` after the loop freeing its elements.

Comment: usually where someone uses malloc or realloc they let a little space null, and I've always used this to break for and while cycles, but in this sample code it doesn't work

Comment: As I wrote, you have not allocated enough memory.

Comment: Ehi @Weather Vane I didn't use it (free(filter)) in this case because it faults before the end of the cycle ;)

Comment: @JoAccount If you take out bufs[j] = 0, you will need to change the way you are checking for the end of the array. Instead of removing bufs[j] = 0, you can realloc bufs to increase the size of bufs by 1 to fit the sentinel value. This can be done by adding bufs = realloc(bufs, (j+1)*sizeof(char*)); before bufs[j] = 0;

Comment: The first time `realloc` is called it must be for *two* array elements: one for the value returned by `strdup` and one for the `NULL` sentinel you use instead of a length count. Ditto subsequently, for further items.

Comment: I've added a new realloc(bufs, j+1*sizeof(char*)) without bufs[j] = 0 before return bufs and it works, but it's strange because many other times similar programs worked well. Is it possible that this likely thing appeared because the machine onto I wrote this is a new 64 bit while I always used 32 bit machines?

Comment: It might have "worked" before because `realloc` and friends may allocate *more* memory than requested, making the *undefined behaviour* benign.

Comment: You don't need *another* `realloc`, you just need to ask for one more than you do. `realloc(bufs, (j+2)*sizeof(char*))`

Comment: @JoAccount: Writing beyond the allocated memory is undefined. It is not recommended to rely on such behavior even if it worked in other cases.

Comment: I've to realloc((j+2)*sizeof(char*)) one time or in the cycle?

Comment: If I put realloc(bufs, (j+2)*sizeof(char*)) in the cycle it allocates a space that is the double of what I need. Where have I to put it?

Comment: Make ONE change only. Change the `1` in `realloc(bufs, (j+1)*sizeof(char*))` to a `2`. End of. It does not allocate double what you need: that's a `j+2` not `j*2`. It allocates one extra element for the `NULL`.

Comment: Sorry if I did get confused, That's my code of course

Comment: If one of these answers solved your problem, please "accept" it.

Answer (score 6):

Your `bufs[j] = 0;` at the end of `read_and_filter` writes into non-allocated memory. You never `realloc`-ed your `bufs` for that extra `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Memory leak is occurring from two places - strdup and the realloc

One answer is to make an initial allocation of memory for the buffer in main, using malloc and then pass a pointer to the allocated memory to the function. The function can then realloc the buffer, and copy data into it.

On return from the function, main can access the data directly from the buffer as it has a valid pointer to it, and then can free that memory before closing.

According to valgrind, the following has no memory loss.

```
void read_and_filter(int fd, char **bufs) {
  char buf[100];
  char ch;
  int j = 0, len = 0, t = 0;
  while (!t && read(fd,&ch,1) == 1) {
    switch (ch) {
    case '\n':
      t = 1;
    case ' ':
      *bufs = realloc(*bufs, (j + 2)*sizeof(char*));
      strncpy(bufs[j++], buf, len);
      memset(buf,0,len);
      len = 0;
      break;
    default:
      buf[len++] = ch;
    }
  }
  bufs[j] = 0;
  return;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char *bptr = malloc(1);
  int fd = open("input.txt", O_RDONLY);

  read_and_filter(fd, &bptr);

  printf("%s\n", bptr);
  free(bptr);
  return 0;
```

However I cannot be sure that this fully replicates the OP's intended functionality, but the overall approach does deal with the memory issues.